# background-image not displaying on ios

Tags: html, ios, css, sass, background-image

I have a weird bug going on in ios. 
I display some user tags using `flexbox` and background-image.

The problem is, the images are not displaying in iPhone/ios. Neither in chrome or safari.

This is my code:

```
<div class="user-container">
  <figure class="user-picture" style="background-image: url(resources/images/user.jpg)"></figure>
  <div class="user-details">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

And my css:

```
.user-container {
   display: flex;
   width: 40%;
   margin: 0 2% 2em;
   min-height: 10em;
}
.user-picture{
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%; 
  min-height: 10em;
  background-position: top center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

The weirdest thing is, in the same page I have a modal popup with the exact same code, and it is displaying the image.

The image is displaying perfectly on android, windows, etc.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

`-webkit-background-size: cover;` in `.user-picture`

and try it should work

so it will be

```
.user-picture{
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%; 
  min-height: 10em;
  background-position: top center;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also add that the `figure` element is only a container element and usually contains an `img` and `figcaption`. It should not replace `img` or take a background image. In your case a `div` would be the best option.

Check out the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure) page for good examples.